# He remained cool as a cucumber

Tags: idioms

Why do we use *cucumber* to describe the attitude of a person who is able to control his/her temper  in front of a difficult event?

Comment: It's a cliché http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/cliche?q=cliché

Comment: @Tristanr: It's not a cliché, it's a [similie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simile)

Comment: Blue, it usually is. It is used so often, that it has become a meaningless habit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This entry in the *Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins* (p133) has the answer:

> It took scientists with thermometers until 1970 to find out what has
>   been folk knowledge for centuries - that cucumbers are indeed cool, so
>   much so that the inside of a field cucumber on a warm day registers
>   about 20 degrees cooler than the outside air. The belief is ancient,
>   but was first put on record by Francis Beaumont and John Fletcher in
>   their play *Cupid's Revenge* (1610), when they referred to certain women
>   as "*as cold as cucumber*".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Shoe's answer, cucumber slices over the eyes are a long-standing folk remedy, rejuvenated into a modern luxury spa treatment. If you've never tried it, [they really do](http://health.howstuffworks.com/skin-care/moisturizing/products/cucumbers-for-eyes.htm) have a soothing, cooling effect even if they weren't previously refrigerated.